# Docker Localhost doesen't work on Firefox but on Chromium, Curl its works

Tags: docker, google-chrome, firefox, localhost

Few weeks ago I installed WEB application (from prepared script - school project), which is runnning via Docker on two containers MySQL and Apache/PHP (web_application). Configuration of this app, provide me forwarding from external port (2000) to internal port in container (80 - http). In this way I had access from Firefox via localhost:2000 to my app inside of docker. Its works perfectly until...

Yesterday, I decided to refresh my OS (Kali Linux).So, I downloaded new version of Linux and install once again . Next, I lunched prepared script to install Docker with containers of my app. I typed localhost:2000 on Firefox and I got error: "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:2000.

On Chrome or via CURL its works well, only Firefox has problem. I tried to downgrade Firefox or install Kali Linux once again but its still doesent work. It's exactly the same app which I lunched before reinstall.

Is this something wrong with my Firefox or new Kali Linux?

Answer (score 0):

if curl in localhost is work so problem is from firefox
use system proxy or no proxy in firefox seting
and open in private tab
hope to work

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried all proxy settings in Firefox and next I tried to run it from private tab and still doesen't work. :(